# Mule geting the payload is not giving the exact string for Special characters such as Ø, €, @

Tags: java, activemq-classic, mule

I am stuck with the below scenario and trying to figure out the exact way of doing it.

Mule is getting the messages from MQ, while I am getting those messages from Mule payload as either in byte or as string, it's not giving the exact characters for the narrow characters, in fact it's getting garbled message for those characters and rest characters are well good.

I tried with getting the payload as string using UTF-8 encoding still have the same output.

Code for the same that I am using is:

```
MuleMessage mmsg = eventContext.getMessage();
byte[] rawMsg = mmsg.getPayloadAsBytes();
```

or

```
String rawMsg = mmsg.getPayloadAsString();
```

or

```
String rawMsg = mmsg.getPayloadAsString("UTF-8");
```

Any workaround or alternative will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mule is taking great care of payload's data encoding so there must be something wrong either in the messages sent to MQ themselves (the publisher may actually badly encode them) or in your own handling of them.

Both the `MuleEvent` and `MuleMessage` classes have a `getEncoding()` method: it's better to use this instead of hard-coding to a particular encoding.

Since you are receiving `javax.jms.BytesMessage`s, I suggest you use a standard transformer to transform it to string instead of doing it yourself, use the following right after your `jms:inbound-endpoint`:

```
<byte-array-to-string-transformer encoding="..." />
```

using the actual encoding used by the publisher that sent the JMS message for the `encoding` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with the getEncoding(), rather its not solve the issue. we are receiving as ByteMessage from sender side. between is this really matters if its bytemessage or text message as I tried to get some bound limit for these types but not able to figure out.

Comment: If you are receiving `BytesMessage`, Mule should create messages with a `byte[]` payload. Do you really need to transform this payload to `String`? If not, leave the payload as `byte[]` and you'll be good.

Comment: Yes david we need to convert it string as we need to manipulate the message and break it into some chunks...we are using mule 3.4, and sample configuration like we have jms inbound and inside composite flow we have a Router class which is implementing callable and overriding the onCall method and from the first line itself we are trying to convert this to string....in between I checked documentation and it says we can define encoding in config file, we are not defining anything, we are simply defining jms inbound with minimal configuration.

Comment: OK, I've reviewed my answer to suggest you use `<byte-array-to-string-transformer />` instead of doing it yourself in code

Comment: ok Thank you ..i will try the same and will update you ..hope this will resolve the issue...a small question , encoding attribute we are not aware of it what sender is using, if we will keep only <byte-array-to-string-transformer> this will be fine or need to know the exact encoding?

Comment: You need to know the exact encoding otherwise the risk is that they use one encoding on one side and you use another (like the default JVM encoding on your side) and you'll have issues with chars above 127. If they would use `TextMessage`s instead of `BytesMessage`s, none of this would be necessary.

Comment: No Good Luck David, still stuck with the same. Here is the steps to replicate, start Active MQ and configure your active MQ que names in mule and from admin console start sending messages like copy right symbol and it will end up with gambelled charecters like ?..One point I noticed is charecters whose asci code is more than 127, they are having problem. few steps I follow like, mentioned encoding type and mime type in mule configuration file where i am configuring the active mq..still stuck with same.. Please bsuggest me any other alternatives as allmost all api provided methods I tried out

Comment: I can totally reproduce this problem but *it is due to the admin console's handling of HTTP POSTed characters*. If I create a simple Java client to send "Ø, €, @" in a `TextMessage` to a queue on an ActiveMQ broker, Mule receives these characters perfectly fine.

Comment: Perfecto, even I reached to till that point..this case of testing from admin, was basically for dev env, where as in other env, we will receive messages from the other party and mule will kicked off once any message in queue arrives..I am facing the same problem also in other env, is there any work around kind of listener or custom transformer from mule side so the characters will not be gambled.

Comment: Really nothing to do. If the other party is using `javax.jms.TextMessage`, there will be no garbling. If you see garbling, they may have encoding issues on their side.

Comment: I've got a similar issue and am outputting message.payloadAs(java.lang.String) but get: [javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler@3d4b5a64, javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler@1e1b7aac, javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler@1e12c1a5]

Answer (score -1):

Try using this expression:

```
#[message.payloadAs(String)]
```

This will give you a payload in String format, so you won't need to use byte-array-to-string-transformer.